# Getting an channel by its ID then sending an message into it

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I am trying to get an channel by its ID then send an message into it. But I am receiving an error when the code is executed.
ERROR:

```
Error sending message to welcome channel.: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'send')
```

I have tried multiple different methods of getting the channel and still no luck.
CODE:

```
const { Client, GuildMember } = require('discord.js');
const Welcome = require('../../models/Welcome');

/**
 *
 * @param {Client} client
 * @param {GuildMember} member
 */
module.exports = async (client, member) => {
  try {
    let guild = member.guild;
    if (!guild) return;

    const welcome = await Welcome.findOne({ guildId: guild.id });
    if (!welcome) return;

    const channel = client.channels.cache.get(welcome.channel)
    channel.send(welcome.message);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(`Error sending message to welcome channel.: ${error}`);
  }
};
```

Comment: Have you tried to log the value of `channel`, `welcome` and `welcome.channel`?

Comment: I have now logged the outputs and they all come back as undefined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my model file for mongodb I had forgotten to define the channel inside of it.
OLD CODE:

```
const { Schema, model } = require('mongoose');

const welcomeSchema = new Schema({
  guildId: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    unique: true,
  },
  message: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
});

module.exports = model('Welcome', welcomeSchema);
```

NEW CODE:

```
const { Schema, model } = require('mongoose');

const welcomeSchema = new Schema({
  guildId: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    unique: true,
  },
  message: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  channel: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  }
});

module.exports = model('Welcome', welcomeSchema);
```